# Enabling the notification feature for my firebase app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have made an app with the use of firebase. It is basically a chat application in which you van send and receive the text and images. I want to add a functionality in it that whenever a user sends a msg, then another user should get a notification . When I try to send a notification through the firebase console, then it is working, but when a user messages through the app, then it is not showing any notification to another user. So, can anyone tell me that how can this functionality be achieved ?Also, provide some sample code to see how things are working

Comment: did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cloud functions for that:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests

First, you can register the user to a `topic`:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Then when the message is sent to the database, you can use `onWrite()` in cloud functions which is a database trigger to be able to send the notification.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events